# Camera launch ignores camera info urls

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using an Orbbec Astra camera with the astra drivers. My launch file looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Bring up Kinect and processing nodelets -->
 <include file="$(find astra_launch)/launch/astra.launch">
<!-- Set cam info URLs, if not in the default location -->
<!-- calib filess -->
 <arg name="rgb_camera_info_url"
      value="file:///home/adrian/CameraCalibration/pruebas/top/holaRGB.yaml" />
 <arg name="depth_camera_info_url"
      value="file:///home/adrian/CameraCalibration/pruebas/top/holaDepth.yaml" />

  <!-- Suppress the default tf transforms (Fuerte only) -->
   <arg name="publish_tf" value="false" />
 </include>

  <!-- Extrinsic transform publisher -->
  <include file="$(find camera_pose_calibration)/blocks/calibration_tf_publisher.launch">
   <arg name="cache_file" value="./extrinsics_cache.bag" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

The problem is that, even though it launches the camera, it completely ignores my camera info urls, where I have the calibration parameters; so my depth image looks completely bad. The output for rostopic echo /camera/depth/camera_info is:

```
header: 
seq: 818
stamp: 
    secs: 1497437986
    nsecs: 339961044
  frame_id: camera_depth_optical_frame
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: plumb_bob
D: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
K: [570.3422241210938, 0.0, 314.5, 0.0, 570.3422241210938, 235.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [570.3422241210938, 0.0, 314.5, 0.0, 0.0, 570.3422241210938, 235.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

---

But in the url file the parameters look like:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: "depth_Orbbec_Orbbec    "
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [586.0295803105151, 0, 325.1107120728067, 0, 585.5541564977655, 242.3986130691661, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [-0.03292964909879049, 0.08060137821556344, -0.001139453780851402, 0.007361020257652488, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [586.5491943359375, 0, 328.8950540238802, 0, 0, 589.6646118164062, 241.3611304274491, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I am trying to calibrate the camera but, if the launch file ignores the files, I am not able to check if the calibration was good.

How can I solve this?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263832/camera-launch-ignores-camera-info-urls/) by [adr_arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30197/adr_arroyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so it actually seems that the driver reads whatever parameters they decide if the parameters in the info url file are completely "crazy" (have values that do not seem adecuate)

Sorry for misunderstanding

---

Originally posted by [adr_arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30197/adr_arroyo/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [deplanque](https://answers.ros.org/users/33966/deplanque/) on 2018-03-05**:
Did you still find out how to use your own calibration file instead of the provided calibration file?

**Comment by [adr_arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30197/adr_arroyo/) on 2018-03-05**:
I dont remember exactly, but I think that you can use any calibration file you want, but the values that you use should be within the tresholds of the values in the camera's drivers. If they are not, the default values will be used